# Which is the prefered way to add function to sockets in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Is there a "prototype" of all sockets connected to socket.io?

I want to define some functions that will be available for each connected socket.

Currently i have:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //Define properties and functions for socket
  socket.hello = function(){
    console.log("hello from "+socket.id);
  }

  socket.hello();
});
```

But i'm defining a 'new' hello function for each socket. Is there a socket prototype? so i can have something like:

```
Socket.prototype.hello = function(){
  console.log("hello from "+socket.id);
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.hello();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, though it doesn't appear to be available through the main `require('socket.io')`.

Currently, you'll have to `require()` [`socket.js`](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/1.3.5/lib/socket.js) directly to reference it:

```
var Socket = require('socket.io/lib/socket');

Socket.prototype.hello = function () {
    console.log("hello from " + this.id);
};
```

> Note: From the `prototype`, you'll have to reference the instance as `this`. A `socket` variable won't already be available.
>
> Also, like the recommendations against modifying native types, like `Object`'s `prototype` -- there's only one `Socket.prototype`, so it's possible to run into collisions of multiple modules trying to define the same method.

Comment: And the "socket.id" from prototype was a typo... but thank you for your clarification :)

Comment: sorry so you need to add this before `var io = require('socket.io')(server);`? Can't get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

Add functions to Socket using typescript

Create a Extension.ts file

```
const Socket = require('socket.io/lib/socket')

declare module 'socket.io' {
    interface Socket {
        getGameKey(this: typeof Socket): string
        getToken(this: typeof Socket): string
    }
}

function getGameKey(this: typeof Socket): string {
    return this.handshake.query.gameKey
}

function getToken(this: typeof Socket): string {
    return this.handshake.query.token
}

Socket.prototype.getGameKey = getGameKey;
Socket.prototype.getToken = getToken;
```

And then import the extension file where you need to access the newly added methods(i.e getToken and getGameKey)

```
import './Extension'

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("Game key "+socket.getGameKey())
    console.log("Token "+socket.getToken())
})
```